# react native slideshow not work correctly

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, slider, slideshow

I use [react-native-slideshow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-slideshow) component in my project but when I went to swiped image it's not paging correctly and do it like a ScrollView.
is there any way to fix it?
or know another slideshow for React native can paging by swiped image correctly?

[image: my problem picture]

Comment: You would have to show us the code.

Comment: exactly I used example code in the library.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like that component does not support the swiping that you want or is not working correctly. A good alternative library that provides swipe gestures and is fairly robust is https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel.

It does support autoplay and you could potentially create your own left right buttons too if that it what you would like.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to `<ScrollView>` in Slideshow.js

```
pagingEnabled={true}
```